# Rules for typecasting with byte

Tags: java, casting

I was just playing around with type casting. Here's the code:

```
class Typecasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       byte b = 3;
       byte c = b++;   // no error
       byte d = b + 1; // error
       byte e = b + b; // error
    }
}
```

Why is there no error in the first line but in second?? Also when i do

```
f = b + 2;
```

I understand that `b` was automatically cast into `int` type and therefore `f` must be `int` type but when I do

```
e = b + b;
```

they both are `byte` type and their result is also in the range of a `byte`, so why can't `e` have `byte` data type? Is it due to the `+` binary operator?

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Your third line is missing a `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+(byte, byte)` returns an `int` per the rules of the language.

The relevant section of the spec is §5.6.2:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using widening conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> - If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> - If either operand is of type `double`,the other is converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`**.

Whereas for `++`, the type of the result is the type of the operand. From the JLS, §15.14.2:

> The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable.

Thus, for `b++`, the result *is* a `byte` and so is assignable to `c`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is there no error in the first line but in second?

Because that's the way the language is defined. There's no `byte + byte` operator, which is why the third line fails - *both* operands are promoted to `int` automatically. From [section 15.18.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> ...
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Now [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) always ends up with a value of `int`, `long`, `float` or `double`... `int` in this case. So the operation is to add two `int` values together, and the result is an `int`.

For `b++`, however, the type is still `byte`. It's a [postfix increment expression (section 15.14.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable.

On a related note, this would be okay:

```
b += 3;
```

That's a [compound assignment (section 15.26.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Note the casting part, which is why it works.

Comment: Ohkay ..thanks
btw if i want to add two byte type and store their value in byte is their any way?? i did something like this 
int z = byte(b + b) but this also gave an error...

Comment: @Smatik: You just need to cast: `byte z = (byte) (b + b);`

Comment: oh i wass missing those brackets around byte... i m such a noob

Answer (score 0):

```
byte d = b+1;
```

In here you are assign int value(b+1) to `byte` d. When you added a int vale to byte value it becomes int value.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte c = b++; //No error;First Line
```

This conforms to [JLS 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

> **The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable.** The result of the postfix increment expression is not a variable, but a value.

```
byte d = b+1;   //error;Second Line
byte e = b+b;    //error;Third line
```

This conforms to [JLS 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.
>
> If this promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.

Read about type promotion in [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

Answer (score 0):

**in line first ++operator returns always operand type result..so it gives no error**

**in second line here 1 is an integer type because all integer type literals is int by default**

**in third line +(byte,byte) returns the integer type that why it will forces you to type cast it into int.**

--> in third line there is always a probability to overflow in byte type..
  ***** if your byte type is defined as constant then it will not force you to typecast because it will alwayz be in range.

Answer (score -1):

When Java performs a sum, it first "transforms" both operands to **int** or **long** (depending of the operands) and the result will be an integer, which will try to assign to your variable of type byte, as it "realizes" the result wont fit in a byte, then it will "complain" and you wont be even able to compile this.